# 2022 Putnam problem A4

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Problem is the following:

Suppose $X_1,X_2,… $
real numbers between $0$
and $1$
that are chosen independently and uniformly at random.

Let $S=∑_{i=1}^kX_i/2^i$
where $k$
is the least positive integer such that $X_k<X_{k+1}$
or $k=∞$
if there is no such integer.

Find the expected value of $S$.

I have some questions about the published solution, or at least, kindly show me why my interpretation of the problem is incorrect so I can move on to other things.

In the published solution , the random variable
$Y=X_21_{k>2}$ is used to find the expectation ($1_.$ being the indicator function), with $\Bbb{E}[Y]=1/6$.  This is true if zero is part of the domain of $X_2$. But if zero is excluded from the support of $X_2$, then it seems that $\Bbb{E}[X_2]=1/3$ , as this piece of Mathematica code shows.

For[i = 1; u = {};, i < 10000, i++, X = RandomReal[1]; Y = RandomReal[1]; If[Y <= X, u = Append[u, Y], {}]]; Mean[u]

So I get different values for the $\Bbb{E}[X_i]$, So what's wrong with this alternative solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't forget that $k > 2$ means $X_1 > X_2$ *and* $X_2 > X_3$.

Comment: so all the complicated proofs I've seen boils down to showing $\Bbb{E}[X_i]= P(X_1>=X_2>=...>=X_{i+1})=1/(i+1)!$. Perhaps a more intuitive approach exists. Thanks.